# Migrating from Apache Commons FileUpload 1.2.2 to FileUpload 2.0.0-M2 issue

Tags: java, file-upload, apache-commons-fileupload

I’m currently working on migrating an existing Java web application that handles file uploads from an HTML form. The application currently uses Apache Commons FileUpload 1.2.2, and I’m aiming to upgrade it to FileUpload 2.0.0-M2. However, I’ve encountered some issues related to deprecated classes during the migration process.
The following snippet shows the code after migration:

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload2.core.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload2.core.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload2.core.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload2.javax.JavaxServletFileUpload;
// some code 
    protected FileItem getFileItem(HttpRequest request,)
    FileItem file = null;
    FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    JavaxServletFileUpload upload = new JavaxServletFileUpload(factory);
    List<FileItems> items = upload.ParseRequest(upload); 
    Iterator iter = items.iterator(); 
    while( iter.hasNext()){
      FileItem item = (FileItem)iter.next();
    // some code
    }
    return file;
  }
```

And for the line   FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
I get a few errors :

> Blockquote
> Multiple markers at this line
> - FileItemFactory is a raw type. References to generic type FileItemFactory should be parameterized
> - The constructor DiskFileItemFactory() is undefined
> - DiskFileItemStreamFactory cannot be resolved to a type
> - FileItemStreamFactory cannot be resolved to a type
> Blockquote
> I’ve searched through the official documentation for FileUpload 2.0.0-M2, but I couldn’t find clear guidance on replacing the deprecated classes.
> Thanks.